# My AzureAD - registered application doesn't have the rights to do anything ...?

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, httprequest, azure-active-directory

I'm writing a c# program right now that tries to authenticate with Azure to make a generic http request. I finally got the code working and I wanted to test the features but for every request I make I get the following error code in response:

`{"error":{"code": "AuthorizationFailed", "message":"The client "(id of the app I registered in AzureAD)" with object id "(same value as before)" does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/read' over scope '/subscriptions/(mysubscriptionid)'."}}.`

The thing is ... The account I use to set everything up is a global admin. I checked every permission box in AzureAD I could find...

(that's 8 Application Permissions and 9 Delegated permissions in the Windows Azure Active Directory API and 1 delegated Permission in the Windows Azure Service Management API, though I don't know why there aren't more possible permissions for Azure Service Management)

the relevant code is rather basic but it works so I don't feel like I need post it, I'll just say that I obtain the Token using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenAsync() with

```
authorityUri = "https://login.windows.net/(mytenantid)",
string resourceUri = "https://management.azure.com/";
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
var res = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, new 
ClientCredential(clientId,clientSecret));
return res.Result;
```

and make the Request to 
`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2016-03-01&$filter=atScope()`

(as an example, this one is supposed to call the roles).

Tried several different types of GET Requests to different URIs, all give similar errors.

I'm thinking it might not be an issue with the code but a setting in the AzurePortal but everything I found there seems set up right (or rather "universal access").

Comment: Do you grant it `Contributor` or `Owner` role? Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role) to grant role.

Comment: Figured I'd forgotten one setting ! Thanks a lot, that did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you forget to grant your service principal. You could add it on Azure Portal. You could grant `Contributor or Owner role` to it.

Please refer to this [link:Assign application to role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).